# How to log errors and retries using AWS SDK Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I want to log only error request and retries request/response.
I tried using

```
        cfg := dax.DefaultConfig()
        cfg.HostPorts = []string{daxConfig.URL}
        cfg.Region = daxConfig.Region
        cfg.LogLevel = aws.LogDebugWithRequestRetries | aws.LogDebugWithRequestErrors
```

But this doesn't log the request body or the response
How to log the request and response body ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom logger with the any name you want I have used customErrorLogger that implements the **'aws.logger'** interface. **'aws.logger'** passed an argument to **'aws.NewClient'** function.

```
type customErrorLogger struct{}

func (l customErrorLogger ) Log(args ...interface{}) {
  
}

func main() {
    sess, err := session.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating session:", err)
        return
    }

    cfg := dax.DefaultConfig()
    cfg.HostPorts = []string{daxConfig.URL}
    cfg.Region = daxConfig.Region
    cfg.LogLevel = aws.LogDebugWithRequestRetries | aws.LogDebugWithRequestErrors

    client := dax.New(sess, cfg)

   
    client.Config.Logger = customErrorLogger {}
}
```

Comment: but aws defaults to stdout? which is what we need

Comment: Custom logger able to log the request and request body along with error requests @PraveshAgarwal

Comment: is there anyway I can use LogDebugWithHTTPBody along with all these

Comment: yes the second alternative will be you can use the 'Custom Retryer' interface along  LogDebugWithHTTPBody